# Vue + Typescript - invalid types

Tags: typescript, webpack, vue.js, tsconfig

Using typescript 2.8.3, ts-loader 3.5.0 (due to usage of webpack 2) and vue 2.5.16 I'm getting an error when trying to define components in a SFC like the following:

```
<script lang="ts">
  import Vue from 'vue'

  export default Vue.extend({
     name: 'TestComponent',

     props: {
       options: {
          type: Array,
          default: () => [],
       }
     },

     computed: {
       getOptions() {
          return this.options
       },
     }
  })
</script>
```

Here's the error:

> TS2339: Property 'options' does not exist on type 'ComponentOptions, DefaultMethods, DefaultComputed,
>   PropsDefinition

Here's the tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "esnext",
    "strict": true,
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "allowJs": true,
    "paths": {
      "test/*": ["test/*"]
    },
    "lib": ["dom", "es2016"],
    "types": ["node", "jest"]
  },
  "include": ["resources/assets/js/**/*.ts", "resources/assets/js/**/*.vue"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules"]
}
```

Any ideas? Works ok if I set "noImplicityThis": false but autocomplete on VSCode is not correct.

Comment: You're missing a closing semicolon for the `options` object definition

Comment: Edited thanks, but that's not why it's not working :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Somehow started working. Changed tsconfig.json to the following:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "esnext",
    "strict": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "noUnusedParameters": true,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "allowJs": true,
    "lib": ["dom", "esnext"],
    "types": ["node", "jest"]
  },
  "include": ["resources/assets/js/**/*.ts", "resources/assets/js/**/*.vue"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules"]
}
```

And vue.d.ts to:

```
declare module '*.vue' {
  import Vue from 'vue'
  export default Vue
}
```

Maybe it's useful for someone.